# Scrollspy active navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

Hi there there are two issues I'm experiencing with Bootstrap Scrollspy

1- When scrolling, the active class does not highlight at the positioned i want to plus section4 for some odd reason does not activate, seen here:

[Scrollspy nav](http://jsfiddle.net/SZYKM/101/)

So scrolling to the section 2:

```
 <h4 id="section2">Section 2</h4>
```

the active state gets active until your halfway in the content...

....So basically I want it to activate as soon as you get the the id(h4) from top and thought all you need would be this:

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#sub-nav' })
```

But no dice..I assume it has something to do with `offset` but not sure how to get it done.

2- The Active state on click gets all messed up: If you click from one place to the next the active goes bonkers and activates a different one.

So is there a solution for these?

Answer (score 0):

1. Problem in your case is because of short content in "section5". When You reach content4 there is also a short offset to content5 so scrollspy automatically check a Section 5 heading

   IMHO the solutions is to add `padding-bottom` to make it longer (look - this one works: http://jsfiddle.net/SZYKM/102/)
2. Problem is because after click on for example `#section3` it automatically jump to top border of container (where scrollspy still doesn't reach #section3 element). IMHO You can change this behaviour to scrolling with any plugin dedicated for it (for example [this one](http://plugins.jquery.com/scrollTo/)) which allows You to control scolling behaviour in more proper way.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Making padding bottom does make the section4 work now, .....but is still doesn't solve the placement when it activates. I appreciate the link but I still need a way to figure it out of Bootstrap function.